# Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool on PHP on Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've just updated my PHP on codeigniter framework. Everything work fine when i run on php 5.6, but when I updated 7.4 I found this error message "Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool". I try everything but didn't work. Here's my code in my controller:

```
        $header = $this->session->userdata('salesinvoiceedit-'.$id_penjualan.$sesi['unique']);
            
        $this->session->set_userdata('salesinvoiceeditawal-'.$id_penjualan.$sesi['unique'],$result);
        $this->session->set_userdata($id_penjualan.'-awal',$arrayBaru);
        
        
        $arrayBaru = array();
        
        foreach($resultitem as $key=>$val){
            $arrayBaru[$val['id_item']] = $val;
        }
            
        $this->session->set_userdata('salesinvoiceeditawal-'.$id_penjualan.$sesi['unique'],$result);
        $this->session->set_userdata($id_penjualan.'-awal',$arrayBaru);
        
        
        if($header['id_penjualan']!=''){
            $header = $header;
            $item   = $this->session->userdata($header['id_penjualan']);
        }else {
            $header = $result;
            $item   = $arrayBaru;
        }
        
        $this->session->set_userdata('salesinvoiceedit-'.$id_penjualan.$sesi['unique'],$header);
        $this->session->set_userdata($id_penjualan,$item);
        $data['main_view']['result']        = $this->session->userdata('salesinvoiceedit-'.$id_penjualan.$sesi['unique']);
        $data['main_view']['resultitem']    = $this->session->userdata($header['id_penjualan']);
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code. I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `$sesi['unique']` is your array, so apparently `$sesi` is a boolean. Find where it's being created/assigned.